# React transition fade between new and old children elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React component rendering a child element via props.children.
The content of this child element is dynamic.
What is the best way to transition (fade out old, fade in new) between these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) for some info on the `ReactTransitionGroup` add-on component. This should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Give this project a try: [react-css-transition](https://wikiwi.github.io/react-css-transition/). It was created out of necessity because the [official](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` was unreliable especially on lower end devices. Scroll down for the *CSS Transition Group* which is what you would need.

** Disclaimer, I'm the creator of react-css-transition*